# Conditional webp and resizing in nginx

Tags: magento2.4, nginx, image-resizing

So regular, webp conditional loading works:

```
 map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
     default "";
     "~*webp" ".webp";
  }
```

with small exception of pulling out of svg to separate location (otherwise there was xml parsing error in browser) and creating additional variable to persist $webp_suffix value

```
    location ~* \.(svg|svgz)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        add_header Vary Accept;
        set $webpvar $webp_suffix;
        try_files $uri$webpvar $uri$webpvar/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

But after enabling offloaded to Nginx images resizing:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)$ {
    set $width "-";
    set $height "-";
    if ($arg_width != '') {
        set $width $arg_width;
    }
    if ($arg_height != '') {
        set $height $arg_height;
    }
    image_filter resize $width $height;
    image_filter_webp_quality 90;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
}
```

There's no more conditional webp loading because of image_filtr module takes original $uri as input.
I've been trying to rewrite or redirect uri but either I end up with a loop and/or with  webp being loaded as text/html with following code:

```
if ($uri !~* /media/(.*)(?:^|\W)webp(?:$|\W)) {
   set $webpmediacheck 1;
 }
if ($uri ~* /media/(.*)(?:^|\W)jpg|jpeg|png(?:$|\W)) {
   set $webpmediacheck 1$webpmediacheck;
 }
if ($webp_suffix = ".webp") {
   set $webpmediacheck 1$webpmediacheck;
 }
if ($webpmediacheck = 111) {
       return 302 $scheme://$host$uri$webp_suffix$is_args$args;
 }
```

Is there any smart way to achieve conditional webp loading and resizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following seems to work quite well:

```
 set $webpmediacheck '';
 set $webpvar $webp_suffix;
if ($uri !~* /media/(?:.+)(\.webp)(?:$|\W)) {
  set $webpmediacheck 1;
}
if ($uri ~* /media/(?:.+)(\.jpe?g|\.png)(?:$|\W)) {
  set $webpmediacheck 1$webpmediacheck;
}
if ($webpvar = ".webp") {
   set $webpmediacheck 1$webpmediacheck;
}
if ($webpmediacheck = 111) {
      rewrite (.+)(\.jpe?g|\.png)($|\W) $1$2$webpvar$3 break;
}

location /media/ {....
```

Unless there's something more clever or performant?